# Updating an entity using EF 4.3 code first

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I have following Entities

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Sections Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Sections : List<Section>, ICollection<Section>
{ }
```

I have added a new Item with Item Id 1 but without any section in it...

Now I want to modify the item and add new section in it, to do that, I am retrieving that item in context and saving it in another context. Here, I have to use two separate context because not sure when user is going to update the object. I can't keep context object open till then.

```
        Item fAp;
        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            fAp = ctx.Items.Include(a => a.Sections).Single(a => a.Id == 1);
        }

        using (var ctx2 = new MyContext())
        {
            var nsec = new Section()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "App Sec...1"
            };

            fAp.Sections.Add(nsec);
            ctx2.Entry(fAp).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx2.SaveChanges();
        }
```

By doing this, new section didn't get added in database. Then I modified the code and added following line before calling ctx2.SaveChanges().

```
            ctx2.Entry(nsec).State = EntityState.Added;
```

It got saved successfully.

Now, my problem is I have very complex data hierarchy, I mean Section class also has many sub navigation property, those properties also have many more, and so forth.

It will be very difficult to keep track of all such properties and set their state manually. How do update the data in this case?

One more thing, I will not be using eager loading, I mean I will not use 'Include' while retrieving an Item object. I will use explicit loading as and when required and finally want to update the object.

Any best suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Setting state affects only that single entity you passed to `Entry` call. Once you use a new context instance for data persistence you must always tell EF state of any entity you want to save.

In your case you need to do either this:

```
ctx2.Items.Attach(fAp); // Now you informed context about existing entity
fAp.Sections.Add(nsec); // Now you told both context and your item that new section exists
```

Or this (preferred solution to avoid some other problems):

```
fAp.Sections.Add(nsec); // Your item is not tracked by the new context yet
ctx2.Items.Add(fAp);     // Now context things that both item and section are new
ctx2.Entry(fAp).State = EntityState.Unchanged; // Make sure that item is not inserted again
```

Or this:

```
fAp.Sections.Add(nsec); // Your item is not tracked by the new context yet
ctx2.Items.Attach(fAp); // Now context things that both item and section are existing
ctx2.Entry(nsec).State = EntityState.Added; // Make sure that section is tracked as new
```

> It will be very difficult to keep track of all such properties and set
>   their state manually. How do update the data in this case?

Your code is doing those changes so it should not be so difficult. You can even add some additional property like `IsDirty` to every entity and use it as helper to track the state of the entity.

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav

I would not be having any control how client is updating my object. I have created repository where client asks for the Item(s). And then again call commit method.

Comment: Since there is a space limitation over here, I have responded it in detail at below...

Answer (score 0):

Updated entity

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Sections Sections { get; set; }
    public OtherInfo Info { get; set; }
}
public class OtherInfo
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

After a retrieving object of Item, user may modify anything. Say example as given above, user is just inserting a new Section and calls commit method by passing object Item.

Commit method in repository class

```
public void Commit(Item fAp)
{
    using (var ct = new MyContext())
    {
        bool isExist = ct.Item.Any(a => a.Id == fAp.Id);
        if (!isExist)
        {
           ct.Items.Add(fAp);
        }
        else
        {
           ct.Items.Attach(fAp);
           ct.Entry(fAp).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        ct.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here in commit method, I will not be aware what user has done with the object. In my test, I have added section and call this method. Since, OtherInfo is not modified, its throwing error saying duplicate primary key for OtherInfo table.

So, in order to make it work, I have to change the status of all entities like

> Section - Added;   OtherInfo - NoChange;   Item - NoChange

It looks difficult to track all entities since structure is bit complex.

Is this approach (commit method) ok or do suggest any better solution?